# How to retrieve specific data from sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

newbie here that is very lost.

I need to retrieve .doc and .pdf files that are stored in Sharepoint. I have a list of ID's (these are in the metadata) of which I want to retrieve all associated files. Preferably as .doc and .pdf, but they are stored internally as BLOBs which would be fine too. I cannot seem to find an easy way to do this, while it seems like a basic task.

Does anyone have advice on how to tackle this? It would save my thesis

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get all attachments from one list?

If so, you could achieve it by PowerShell script. For more detailed information, you could refer to the post below.

[How to get all attachment from the list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113729/how-to-get-all-attachment-from-the-list)

And you also could achieve it by C#. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Accessing and Saving List Item Attachments.](https://www.developer.com/net/Accessing-and-Saving-List-Item-Attachments.htm)

And you also could achieve it by REST API and JavaScript. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[How to: Get list item attachments using REST and JavaScript in SharePoint 2013.](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/06/27/how-to-get-list-item-attachments-using-rest-and-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry for the unclarity - I want to get the documents of specific persons (1300+) in the huge list (55000+).